# SCSS @extend in @keyframes is not working

Tags: css, sass, css-animations, extend

im trying to create two keyframes animations which replace the content attribute of a pseudo element. Unfortunately, it looks like the `@extend` feature of SCSS is not working within `@keyframes`. Did i miss something?

Code: *(**open** animation does not work, **close** does).*

```
@keyframes open {
  0% {
    @extend .icon-after-arrow-down;
  }
  50% {
    color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    @extend .icon-after-arrow-up;
  }
}

@keyframes close {
  0% {
    content: '\e905';
  }
  50% {
    color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    content: '\e902';
  }
}
```

Comment: @extend is when you need to chains classes, you should use mixins for this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by comment from @Arkellys
*"@extend is when you need to chains classes, you should use mixins for this case."*